# Alignment of UIImageView within UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I see this topic in quite a few places but I can't figure out why exactly my code doesn't work.

I have an image of an artificial horizon that goes from -90 to 90 degrees. I want to view it through a small window which just shows around -20 to 20 degrees. Then I want to move the image up and down based on the angle my robot is leaning.

I started by adding a UIImage to a UIImageView. All of the alignment is correct. Then I thought the easiest way to move the image up and down was to add the UIImageView to a UIScrollView. Now I can't figure out how to get the alignment right. I see the image in there if I drag in the scrollview but as soon as I let go it goes back to where it was.

Here is the code I have. This is the first Swift code I have written so if there is a better way to do this I welcome any ridicule (just kidding, be gentle)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width / 2 - 100, self.view.frame.height / 2, 200, 200)

    self.myImageView = UIImageView.init()
    self.myImageView = UIImageView(frame: imageRect)
    self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    self.myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.myImageView.image = UIImage.init(named:"horizon")
    //self.view.addSubview(self.image)


    self.myScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: imageRect)
    self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageRect.width, height: imageRect.height)

    self.myImageView.center = self.myScrollView.center
    self.myScrollView.frame = imageRect
    self.myScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.myScrollView.addSubview(self.myImageView)
    self.view.addSubview(self.myScrollView)

    /////////


    self.connectionStatusLabel.text = "Disconnected"
    self.connectionStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.textBox.font = UIFont(name: self.textBox.font!.fontName, size: 8)

    // Watch Bluetooth connection
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.connectionChanged(_:)), name: BLEServiceChangedStatusNotification, object: nil)


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.dataReceived(_:)), name: BLEDataChangedStatusNotification, object: nil)


    // Start the Bluetooth discovery process
    btDiscoverySharedInstance
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the scrollView's contentSize to the actual image size not the imageView's size. And set the imageView's size to the actual image size as well:

```
let image = UIImage.init(named:"horizon")
// Set the imageView's size to the actual image size
self.myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
...
...
// Set the scrollView's contentSize to the actual image size
self.myScrollView.contentSize = image.size
```